# ZF3: Throwing and catching exception

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception, zend-framework3

In my IndexController indexAction, I'm trying to throw and catch exception, then in the catch block, I want to do something, like so:

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function indexAction() {
        try {
            throw new \Exception('My exception error messag.');
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            echo '111';
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

When the exception is thrown, instead of printing "111" and stopping, it renders view "myproject/module/Application/src/view/error/index.phtml" with the exception message I've thrown "My exception error messag". Like the following screenshot:

[image]

I found out in "myproject/config/development.config.php" I have something like this:

```
return [
    'view_manager' => [
        'display_exceptions' => true,
    ],
];
```

I tried changing that to false, I got the output:

[image]

Which means it's still showing the error/index view but it just doesn't display the exception details

What I want is simply an output of "111".

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but you are throwing the exception and you are asking how to stop it from showing?

Comment: @Script47 1- I'm throwing the exception (which is ok), 2- then catching it, but instead of printing 111, it renders error/index !

Comment: But I don't see where you are telling it to print 111.

Comment: @Script47 I'm sorry, my mistake while writing the question, fixed it. It's in the catch block

Comment: It seems to work for me [here](https://eval.in/870161).

Comment: @Script47 That's pure php, I'm trying that in Zend Framework 3

Comment: Possibly [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024394/how-to-correctly-set-up-exception-handler-in-zend)?

Comment: NEVER CALL EXIT() FROM WITHIN A CLASS METHOD!  It's a very bad practice to do that because you'll bypass a lot of the normal program flow if you do it.  I think only class destructors and functions installed with register_shutdown_function() will run.  You should normally only use exit() in shell scripts and the like.

Comment: @GordonM I used that only for demonstrating the example. Thanks. Can you share a link/source about this topic please?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is by @Gordon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13108619/134824). I'll not delete this question and answer here since that question and answer were about ZF2 while this one is about ZF3.

Just like ZF2, the issue is to do with namespacing.

```
try {
    throw new \Exception('My exception error messag.');
} catch(\Exception $e){// <<< Use \Exception instead of Exception
    echo 111;
    exit;
}
```

or like Gordon said, `use \Exception;` in top of file so we can replace \Exception with Exception.